# pipe is not a function

Tags: nodejs

estoy tratando de usar el modulo [node-ds4](https://github.com/ehd/node-ds4)

mi codigo es este:

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
var ds4 = require('ds4');
var through = require('through');

var hid = new HID.HID('\\\\?\\hid#vid_054c&pid_05c4#6&22a63115&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}');

hid.pipe(through(ds4.parseDS4HIDData)).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Al correr el programa me dice que hid.pipe no es una funcion

Estube leyendo un poco y pipe es una funcion de node que lee buffers.
Siguiendo la documentacion de [node-hid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-hid) puedo leer los datos usando:

```
hid.on('data', function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

y en consola se muestra algo asi:

```
<Buffer 01 79 80 83 79 08 00 b8 00 00 d1 b3 0f 05 00 fd ff 00 00 25 ff e3 1e 05 07 00 00 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 00 ... >
<Buffer 01 79 80 83 79 08 00 bc 00 00 b2 b6 0f 06 00 fd ff fc ff 0d ff 2f 1f 41 07 00 00 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 00 ... >
<Buffer 01 79 80 83 79 08 00 c0 00 00 a2 b9 0f 01 00 ff ff ff ff fd fe fb 1e 05 07 00 00 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 00 ... >
```

¿Porque pipe no esta funcionando siendo que hid si es un buffer? 
¿necesito instalar algún otro modulo que me permita usar pipe?

pregunta extra:
¿como puedo hacer que console.log() NO cree otra linea con datos y remplace la que ya existe?

Comment: Según leo en la documentación de node-hid ya que nunca había escuchado de eso, veo que en realidad el buffer es el data que te llega en `hide.on('data')`, por lo que le estas pasando una funcion pipe a un objeto que no es un buffer, deberias intentar ejecutar esta linea dentro del evento `data.pipe(through(ds4.parseDS4HIDData)).pipe(process.stdout);`

Comment: Tambien lo intente, pero obtengo el mismo error

Comment: Pero notaste que le cambié el objeto?. es decir, no estas llamando el pipe de `hid` si no el pipe de `data`

Comment: si, lo intente de las 2 formas... llamando a hid.pipe y a data.pipe. de las dos formas obtengo el error de que pipe no es una funcion

Comment: Bueno, ahora leyendo la documentacion de node, veo que los buffers no tienen la funcion pipe, dicha funcion es perteneciente a los procesos... en ese caso, que quieres hacer con tu buffer, para leerlo no te basta pasarle un `buffer.toString('utf8')`?

Comment: ahora me puse a leer el código de la libreria node-ds4 y me doy cuenta que lo que hace es generar el buffer de la misma manera que lo hago solo con hid y nunca utiliza el pipe. 

como dices pipe solo lee todo el proceso que hace ds4-dump o algo asi... tendré que leer bien la documentación para entender esto por ahora ya lo resolvi. 

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguro que instalaste la lib?

```
$ npm install -g ds4
```

generaste el dump?

```
$ ds4-dump
```

asegúrate de utilizar -g cuando instalas la libreria

Comment: que diferencia hace instalar globalmente? parece que eso era lo que me faltaba... tenia instalada la libreria pero no globalmente.

Comment: @RodrigoMartín cuando aparece ese error que no es `una funcion` es sinonimo que se instalo la libreria